# What am I doing wrong in defining my function to get the error "numpy.ndarray" not callable?

Tags: python, numpy

This is my code:

```
def lsf2(x,y): 
   N = 100
   A = (sum(x)*sum(y))/(sum(x)*(1-n))
   B = (sum(y)-N*A)/sum(x)
   delta = N*(sum(x**2)*sum(y))- sum(x)*sum(x*y)
   sigy = (sum(y-A-B*x)**2/(N-2))**0.5
   siga = sigy(sum(x)**2)/delta
   sigb = sigy*(N/delta)**0.5

  return A, B, sigy, siga, sigb 

A, B, sigy, siga, sigb = lsf2(xdata, ydata)


print(A, B, sigy, siga, sigb)
```

The error I get is this:

> ----> 7     siga = sigy(sum(x)**2)/delta
>
> TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

Comment: What are you trying to do on that line of code? Python thinks you are trying to call a function named `sigy`, but this name refers to a numpy array, not a function.

Comment: please give us sample data to work on. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
sigy = (sum(y-A-B*x)**2/(N-2))**0.5
siga = sigy(sum(x)**2)/delta
```

`sigy` is a numpy array. When you type `sigy(sum(x)**2)/delta` you try to pass `sum(x)**2` as input as if `sigy` was a function **but it is not.**

**Maybe you need:**

```
siga = sigy*(sum(x)**2)/delta # multiplication
```

**or**

```
siga = sigy**(sum(x)**2)/delta # power
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you that you are trying to call a function with `sigy(...)` but `sigy` is an array not a function. Based on the line following the one with the error, I think you are missing a `*`:

```
siga = sigy*(sum(x)**2)/delta
           ^ here
```

In math, we can write something like `x(a+b)` and we assume that the value of `x` is multiplied by the result inside the parentheses. In Python, this same syntax means to pass the value inside the parentheses to the function named `x`. You cannot leave out the multiplication operator in a Python program.

Answer (score -1):

`sigy` is a numpy array, not a function. In the line `siga = sigy(sum(x)**2)/delta`, the `sigy()` is trying to call a function with the name `sigy` and argument `sum(x)**2`. If you are trying to index `sigy` you need to use `[]` like `sigy[index]`.